# Drupal 6: No forum index page (Advanced Forum)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, indexing, forum

I've got a strange senario/question for you.

I'm running drupal 6 with advanced forum (although my problem doesn't go away if I just use the forum module that comes with drupal)! Everything has been fine and so I've left it untouched (not open to the public) for about a month while I've been sorting out legal work...

I came back to it a few days ago only to find 'http://mysite.com/forum' (I'm using clean URL's) does not exist!

I've tried everything I can think of! Even silly things like 'http://mysite.com/forum **s**'. But it doesn't even appear to be there  in Content Management > Content!

I can get to the individual posts and  even the individual catergory/containers - I'm just missing the index page!

I've tried disabling and re enabling the advanced forum module, reseting it's settings and even clearing the site cache! Non of which made any difference! I was going to try typing the node in, but I wasn't sure what it was!...

Please help me as soon as possible!

Thanks in advance,

Andy

---

Latest

---

Okay, just to clarify exactly what's happening and what I've done so far after 'ax's' wonderful assitants:
**Whats Happening** is, I get Drupal's 404 Page Not Found message/page when trying to get to www.mysite.com/forum! The strange thing is though, by typing the URL of the individual sections/catergorys I can see them, and all the posts inside etc!

**I have**, been into sites/all/modules/advanced_forum/advanced_forum.module and look at the variables in the `advanced_forum_page($tid=0)` function.
First, I just created a post/topic in the forum `var_dump`ing all the variables in the function! They all returned NULL.
But then in the function, I one by one `var_dump`ed all the variables, after the line they were first used (in the function), I deleted the `var_dump` line for each variable after I refreshed the forum page, so there was only one `var_dump` in the function at once. The strange thing was nothing appeared on the page, even when I tried `drupal_set_message(print_r($variable));!

So, I don't know and I just need it fixing asap please! ... Thanks in Advance

Comment: which version of the advanced_forum module are you using? are the dependency modules (Author Pane, Forum, Taxonomy, Comment) installed and enabled? see "Missing Forum Index when Advanced Forum enabled", http://drupal.org/node/601030 , for a similar issue.

Comment: I am using Advanced Forum 6.x-1.1 and 'Yes', all the required are installed and enabled

Comment: can you do the following query in mysql / phpmyadmin and post the result?: `SELECT * FROM menu_router WHERE path = 'forum'`

Comment: if there is no result, then there is a problem with your `menu_router` table. if there is a result, the `page_callback` column should have the value `advanced_forum_page`, meaning that http://mysite.com/forum should call `function advanced_forum_page($tid = 0)` in advanced_forum.module. you could do some debugging (ie. `var_dump($forums); exit;`) there to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Hi, I will just do that and reply back as soon as I can. Sorry about my slowness - I had to go out!

Comment: Hi, I did the MySQL query and sure it returned the results you said, so now your saying I need to debug!? One problem, I'm not confident with debugging anything, no matter about drupal modules! Could I have some further assitants with this please...

Comment: just try debugging - it's good for life! :) `var_dump` the variables in `function advanced_forum_page($tid = 0)`, one by one, and see what they return. have to go out now, too.

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied sooner, i got ingrossed in Java - debugging. So I tell I lie, I can debug, in familar programming langauges but drupal is not one of them! Anyway, I tried to use var dump, but I'm not sure I used it in the right way because every variable returned NULL! All I did was create **a new forum topic**, in a random section with the following code `<?php var_dump($forum_per_page); var_dump($sortby); var_dump($forums); var_dump($parents); var_dump($topics); ?>`! Was this the right thing to do? What should I do now?

Comment: you don't have to create new topics. see if `function advanced_forum_page($tid = 0)`, the function that should be called when you are visiting http://mysite.com/forum , is being called, and what is happening there. to do this, add `var_dump($some_variable); exit;` (the `exit` so you don't get the whole remaining Drupal stuff) to the function, starting at the first line of the function and going down (and the visit http://mysite.com/forum ). what does `theme('forums', $forums, $topics, $parents, $tid, $sortby, $forum_per_page)` return?

Comment: Hi, Just to let you know. I am still using this 'question' and I will reply, I'm just a bit busy at the minute so it might be a while before I do! I'll get that bit of debugging done as soon as possible (now I know how to do it) and post the results for further investigation... Please bare with me though! Thanks for helping & understanding!

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure I'm doing this right at all. I have/will ammend my qustion to tell you exactly what I've done and what's going on! ( the sections 'latest'). Please help asap, if it's going to be like this, is there a way I can backup **just the posts** or something so I can just reinstall Advanced Forum etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out what was going on, and therefore was able to sort my problem out myself!

It was the most stupid thing as well. For some reason, I had an empty folder called... you guessed, 'forum' in the root of my website and as soon as I deleted it, I saw my forum index for the first time in ages.

Obviously, Drupal was looking in the folder instead of using the module etc... (You Know...)

Anyway, thanks for your attempts to help me - much appreciated!

-- Andy

Comment: you see: using your own brain pays off :) who else could have thought of that folder ...

Comment: :) ! Gotta start using using that thing (my brain)! I guess you wouldn't of thought to ask me that in a million years, and if you did I'd of probably thought you were stupid or winding me up etc. Anyway, it's fixed now! Thanks for your time and kindness etc ax! Much appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can try two solution:

1. Reinstall the module instead of deactivating and reactivating it (you will lose your current categorization, however it seems like your forum is empty right now).
2. Build a new installation to make some tests, enable the advanced forum module and take a look at the index page of the forum to see if it's replicable.

Take a look at the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/advanced_forum?status=All&categories=All) of the module too, maybe someone else had the same problem.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I don't really feel the need for solution 2, from past experience etc, plus I haven't really got the time but I can see where your coming from. As for solution, is their anyway I can back up everything (or atleast the posts, topics and containers) first, because as I said they are still there and it took quite a long time to create them! But if worst comes to worst, I'll just have to copy and paste everything! I'll check the issue queue out as well though...